# ¿Como puedo quitar una linea que me aparece en una imagen que esta en una etiqueta <a>?

Tags: html, css

Mi problema es quizá de css, pero no he podido dar con la solucion, tengo 3 iconos en una tabla, que los estoy incrustando en una etiqueta  para poder redireccionar a las vistas o a peticiones, solo que cuando les di estilo de ponerlas verticalmente y darles el ancho se ve una raya en las separaciones, les dejo mi codigo ojala me aya explicado y que me puedan apoyar.

```css
div.cuerpoPrincipal div.tablas .divTablaIconos {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  div.cuerpoPrincipal div.tablas .divTablaIconos a img{
    width: 35px;
  }
```

```html
<tr class="resultados">
  <td class="resultados">5</td>
  <td class="resultados">bermoth</td>
  <td class="resultados">centro estatal del gob michoacan</td>
  <td class="resultados">412540</td>
  <td class="resultados">
    <div class="divTablaIconos">
        <a href="#" onclick="editar();">
          <img src="../images/iconos/tablas/editar.png">
        </a>
        <a href="#" onclick="editar();">
          <img src="../images/iconos/tablas/imprimir.png">
        </a>
        <a href="#" onclick="editar();">
          <img src="../images/iconos/tablas/menu.png">
        </a>
    </div>
  </td>
```

[image: imagen del problema]

Comment: creo que se debe a que estas usando <a> como contenedor de la imagen, yo reemplaze la etiqueta <a> por <div> y se arreglo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que estas viendo es la clásica linea de subrayado que tienen los links de forma nativa en html. Podes desactivarla mediante la propiedad `text-decoration: none;`

```css
div.cuerpoPrincipal div.tablas .divTablaIconos {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  div.cuerpoPrincipal div.tablas .divTablaIconos a img{
    width: 35px;
  }
  
.divTablaIconos a{
    text-decoration: none;
  }
```

```html
<tr class="resultados">
  <td class="resultados">5</td>
  <td class="resultados">bermoth</td>
  <td class="resultados">centro estatal del gob michoacan</td>
  <td class="resultados">412540</td>
  <td class="resultados">
    <div class="divTablaIconos">
        <a href="#" onclick="editar();">
          <img src="../images/iconos/tablas/editar.png">
        </a>
        <a href="#" onclick="editar();">
          <img src="../images/iconos/tablas/imprimir.png">
        </a>
        <a href="#" onclick="editar();">
          <img src="../images/iconos/tablas/menu.png">
        </a>
    </div>
  </td>
```

Comment: muchas gracias si me sirvio asi te agradezco mucho tu apoyo.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que con una pequeña modificación, podría funcionar, simplemente colocar **a href=...** dentro de la etiqueta **img**, si no funciona, deberías proporcionarnos tu **css**, para ver que está pasando.

```css
div.cuerpoPrincipal div.tablas .divTablaIconos {
    display: inline-block;
}

div.cuerpoPrincipal div.tablas .divTablaIconos a img{
    width: 35px;
}
```

```html
<tr class="resultados">
  <td class="resultados"> 5 </td>
  <td class="resultados"> bermoth </td>
  <td class="resultados"> centro estatal del gob michoacan </td>
  <td class="resultados"> 412540 </td>
  <td class="resultados">
    <div class="divTablaIconos">            
      <img a href="#" onclick="editar();" src="../images/iconos/tablas/editar.png">           
      <img a href="#" onclick="editar();" src="../images/iconos/tablas/imprimir.png">            
      <img a href="#" onclick="editar();" src="../images/iconos/tablas/menu.png">
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo te agrdezco tu ayuda tambien el tuyo me funciono muchas gracias.

Comment: @Abdiel, Un placer poder colaborar.